# Some products not showing in listing page and search - Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, products

I have an issue on my website: **some products are not showing in category page and search**. I have created new product it is also not showing in category page, but is showing for a brand page i have extension "aitmanufacture".

For example i have a category called "DEMO" it has 40 products, but it's showing only 30 products remaining 10 products not showing. i have reviewed all the options like qty,status,visibilty and backend also category page it's showing 40.. it's seems everything fine but it's not showing in frontend.

Help please.

Comment: Hi Mohan, first check whether all products assigned to your main webste or not.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do in this case is to reindex all your products, the best way to do this is by a command line at the root of your website:

```
php shell/indexer.php reindexall
```

You can also do it via the admin by going to

System -> Index Management

but you may encounter a timeout if you have many products / attributes.

In order to see your products in the results page, make sure prior to reindexing that you have set your attributes "searchable" by going to the

Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes

page and check if the attributes used for your products are set correctly.